# What is the value that Jenkins provides in the Salesforce ecosystem?

Tags: appexchange, jenkins

I believe that it provides just automated builds, which can be paired up with automated testing. Is there any other value?

How can developers collaborate and gain more visibility by using Jenkins?
How does Jenkins help to streamline release management processes? Developers hand off the code to Release managers to deploy the code.
How does Jenkins help with governance and change management processes?

Answer (score 4):

Great answer @jhersh, I would like to add a few more inputs

@JoshBirk published a brilliant [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-for-force-com-continuous-integration.html) on DFC portal which answers most of the answers that you are looking for.

> How can developers collaborate and gain more visibility by using
>   Jenkins?  How does Jenkins help to streamline release management
>   processes?

[image]

> So even with multiple developers working on fragmented instances,
>   you’ll have one testing instance which attempts to build the current
>   state of the project based on source control.  Failures get sent out
>   so that they can be fixed as part of the cycle.

Next question

> Developers hand off the code to Release managers to deploy the code.
>   How does Jenkins help with governance and change management processes?

Jenkins provides a [Release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin) to help streamline release management. The idea is to automate builds and provides continous integrating thereby eliminating manual bottlenecks in the release process.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins is just a tool like any other. It is commonly associated with CI (continuous integration), which tends to mean things like running all of your tests after every commit, helping to evaluate pull requests and other proposed changes, and so on. We also use Jenkins for periodic jobs, almost like `cron`, that aren't necessarily associated with any one repo.

Jenkins can run most any old script you throw at it, and much of what you're asking is up to your particular deployment of Jenkins. Your second paragraph is really another world entirely.

> How can developers collaborate and gain more visibility by using Jenkins?

Jenkins is not a collaboration tool like Github issues or Trello cards or StackOverflow or even dead-tree post-it notes. It just builds stuff, for values of "builds" and "stuff" that you define yourself.

> How does Jenkins help to streamline release management processes?

You are thinking of CD (continuous deployment), the idea that each successful build in Jenkins could, in turn, initiate a deployment. This is certainly configurable in Jenkins. Even without CD, you could consider your "release management processes" to be "streamlined" with CI alone, as it can help build confidence in the quality of your code.

> How does Jenkins help with governance and change management processes?

Again, that's entirely up to you. What does "governance" and "change management" mean in your business? If it means running a linter script, or checking your code against some set of standards, Jenkins may be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a functional example of how Jenkins can work for managed package development when combined with other tools such as GitHub and Ant build scripts, check out [CumulusCI](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI) which we've built at the Salesforce Foundation over the last 1.5 years to manage our development and release process.  We open sourced all the scripts that make the process work.

You didn't clarify if this is to manage the customizations in a single Salesforce implementation or to build installable packages on the platform.  Our process is definitely geared towards the later.

I presented a session at Dreamforce last year, [Automating the Impossible: End to End Team Development for ISVs](http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/qWZdC_n0I8OagLzg_RJmIA), which is a good overview of our process and how Jenkins fits into it.

One way that CumulusCI helps with streamlining release management is by automatically creating beta managed packages for you anytime you merge code into your master branch.  All development is done in feature branches and merged into master after being fully tested using a GitHub Pull Request.  This allows complete isolation of all work as well as providing way of tracking code reviews and merges.  We also use tags in GitHub to mark the exact code used to build a particular package version.

One key point I've settled on is that Jenkins is actually the wrong place to start thinking about development and release management.  The first thing you need to do is get your code into version control, then focus on build scripts that are capable of automating the different types of builds you'll need in your development process.  At that point, you can start looking at Jenkins or similar tools to automate the execution of build scripts integrated with your version control system.  Starting with Jenkins is putting the cart before the horse.